# ARC: "Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership"

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am upgrading an iOS 4 project to use ARC with the sdk5.
So I want to use the automatic refactor method for converting the code to use ARC.

Unfortunately, it doesn´t work.

```
for(id* child in childObjectArray){
    [child removeParentGroupReferences];
}
```

I get a lot of errors including

> Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Change `id*` to `id`. `id` is already defined as an object pointer.

Comment: i had the same error, but in CoreData.framework. What should i do?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Stupid typo caused me a world of grief.

Answer (score 6):

`id` is a type, not an object. That means that id shouldn't be a pointer. Remove the `*` to fix it.

```
for(id child in childObjectArray){
    [child removeParentGroupReferences];
}
```