# Importing Core Data to existing project fails

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a workspace and I'm trying to add Core Data to it.  I went to the project I want to add Core Data to, selected the Target, hit the + sign under Link Wit Binary Files and added the Core Data framework.  That part works fine.  I can build and run.  When I try the next and using this line:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

I get build errors.  These build errors look like:

```
"ARC Semantic Issue"
Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership
```

These errors are present in

```
NSEntityDescription.h
NSManagedObjectModel.h
NSMnagedObject.h
NSManagedObjectContext.h
NSPersistentStore.h
```

Does anyone know why I'm not able to import Core Data to an existing iOS project?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9263875/529243 ?

Comment: @DanFairaizl Using Xcode 4.6.3

Comment: @Mundi Yes I am using ARC which is weird since the errors seem to imply I'm not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as adding CoreData.framework to your target:

[image]

Click the plus button (+) under *Linked Frameworks and Libraries*

Then in your Prefix file (Tabs-Prefix.pch in this case) in the `#ifdef __OBJC__` declaration:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #impport <CoreData/CoreData.h> //Added core data here
#endif
```

If this does not work, perhaps you have an older version of Xcode installed and the paths are messed up. It could be trying to import an older framework.

Comment: @DanFairazl That is what I've tried.  But I get those errors.  I tried it in the latest developer preview and now I get, Command /Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: @Crystal there have to be more error messages than that. What's the build output?

Comment: Ok, I added the complete build output.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Crystal my only other thought is to check where the framework is located on disk. The file inspector in Xcode will show you when CoreData.framework is selected. Mine is located: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework

Comment: Mine looks to be in the same place.  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework

Comment: I decided to just reset my working changes and do it again.  Somehow this time it worked.  Weird.

Answer (score 2):

In my framework search paths, I had an erroneous path that correctly built once I removed it:

```
$(DEVELOPER_DIR)/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be related to your entity definitions. Is it possible that you have declared entities that use the attribute name `id`? That would typically be a `NSNumber` type in the model subclasses, i.e. `*id`.

It seems that in this case, the compiler instead of complaining about the `*id` in the class files, it indicates the `id` in the header files, which is confusing.

--> Try changing your attribute names.

Comment: I haven't even started creating entities.  I added the CoreData framework and god build errors once I added the import statement to the .pch.

Comment: Still, other classes might be using `id`. Try a global text search.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved by the following steps:

1. Remove Reference to `CoreData.framework` from Frameworks group in Xcode.
2. Remove `CoreData.framework` from 'Link Binary with Libraries' in target settings.
3. Quit Xcode (`Cmd` + `Q`).
4. Open your project folder in Finder and delete `CoreData.framework` file.
5. Start Xcode, open your project. Now you may to add the `CoreData.framework` in 'Link Binary with Libraries'.
6. Don't forget to add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` into `<projectName>-Prefix.pch` located at Supported Files. My prefix header seems like this:

`

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
```

`

I don't know how existance of any file in project directory can affect to compile errors, but it works for me.

Hope this helps for anyone who reads it.